# Sociolinguistics VS Rhetoric

Tags: terminology, sociolinguistics, discourse

Can anyone tell me major differences between rhetoric and sociolinguistics? And what theoretical commonalities they share?

I'm a rhetoric student, and I'm looking to go to grad school, but I'm not sure whether I should shift to sociolinguistics. My reason for possibly changing is because I read a lot of material on identity, semantics, and discourse, and it seems that all the writers and editors of such material happen to be professors in sociolinguistics.

Is sociolinguistics the new rhetoric?

Comment: I can't think of any way in which they're at all similar - why do you think they are???

Comment: Isn't rhetoric similar to stylistics (a la Michael Riffattere)? I can see though how sociolinguistics and rhetoric may overlap in certain areas.

Answer (score 1):

*The following answer by [Canary Wharf](//academia.stackexchange.com/users/39434/canary-wharf) was posted to the [closed cross-posted version of the question on Academia](//academia.stackexchange.com/q/62307/7734). I am posting it here to save it from deletion:*

Ph.D. student in sociolinguistics here.

Rhetoric is likely to be centered on how to make language do particular things. Communicating clearly, making and structuring arguments, persuasiveness, word choice, writing techniques, finding fallacies in other people's logic, etc. Deliberateness and how to make language work for your purposes.

Sociolinguistics has more to do with speech communities and how people use language in particular contexts. Dialects, sex effects, multilingualism in society, pidgins and creoles, language variation and change over time, and the like. This is much more observation-based. Language data that you get to pick apart to find the patterns and their social/linguistic meaning.

Overlap might occur the most readily when it comes to pragmatics – i.e. things language does beyond the literal level – and discourse analysis and/or conversation analysis, which are like taking a magnifying glass to examples of real conversation and seeing what’s happening on basically the molecular level. For instance, how long is *that* particular pause and why did it happen where it did between the speakers?

I think of rhetoric as more of something that falls under the aegis of the humanities, and sociolinguistics as a social science. Especially variationist sociolinguistics, which is deeply quantitative and relies on statistical analysis.

Comment: Indeed... rhetoric is how to calculate and produce an effect with language, sociolinguistics is studying how people in fact use language. That said, the asker being a "rhetoric student" in this day and age suggests that he is studying the history/development of rhetoric, hence more or less how people have been (intentionally) using language. P.S. Not sure if this comment is of any use on the X-posted copy...